# R Shiny - how do I trigger an event when bs4Dash::box() object is maximized?

Tags: r, shiny

As the title suggests, I'm trying to trigger an event to occur when I maximize/un-collapse a box(). The code below doesn't work (`Error in : shinyjs: Invalid shiny tags given to hidden`) but it's more or less what I'm trying to do.

The box object is a bs4Dash::box.

How do I accomplish this?

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  bs4Dash::box(id = "myBox", "This is my box")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  observe({
    if (shinyjs::hidden("myBox")) {
      # do something when the box is collapsed
      print("Box is collapsed!")
    }
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45462614/how-to-see-if-a-shiny-dashboard-box-is-collapsed-from-the-server-side) might be helpful.

Comment: @YBS Unfortunately that solution isn't working for me. The `input$iscollapsebox1` object remains NULL, making me think the JS code part of the solution is failing for some reason. When I have time, I'll edit my question to include that attempt.

Comment: Apologies @YBS. I wasn't aware I was using a bs4Dash box. I've edited the question to reflect that.