# How to see if a shiny dashboard box is collapsed if it is produced by renderUI?

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I have a (varying) number of collapsible boxes in my R shiny app produced by renderUI/uiOutput and I would like to see whether they are collapsed or not from the server. There is a question and answer on how to do this when the boxes are defined inside the ui [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45462614/how-to-see-if-a-shiny-dashboard-box-is-collapsed-from-the-server-side?noredirect=1&lq=1) but this doesn't work when I create the boxes inside the server-function. However, collapsing them programmatically still works fine. This is how it looks like right now:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyjs)

jscode <- "
shinyjs.collapse = function(boxid) {
$('#' + boxid).closest('.box').find('[data-widget=collapse]').click();
}
"
collapseInput <- function(inputId, boxId) {
  tags$script(
    sprintf(
      "$('#%s').closest('.box').on('hidden.bs.collapse', function () {Shiny.onInputChange('%s', true);})",
      boxId, inputId
    ),
    sprintf(
      "$('#%s').closest('.box').on('shown.bs.collapse', function () {Shiny.onInputChange('%s', false);})",
      boxId, inputId
    )
  )
}

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    useShinyjs(),
    extendShinyjs(text = jscode, functions = c("collapse")),
    actionButton("bt1", "Collapse box1"),
    actionButton("bt2", "Collapse box2"),
    br(), br(),
    # This is where the boxes were defined in the original question & answer
    # box(id = "box1", collapsible = TRUE, p("Box 1")),
    # box(id = "box2", collapsible = TRUE, p("Box 2")),
    uiOutput("boxes"), # This does not exist in the original
    collapseInput(inputId = "iscollapsebox1", boxId = "box1"),
    verbatimTextOutput(outputId = "res")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$boxes <- renderUI({ # This does not exist in the original
    do.call(tagList, 
            list(box(id = "box1", collapsible = TRUE, p("Box 1")),
            box(id = "box2", collapsible = TRUE, p("Box 2")))
            )
  })
  observeEvent(input$bt1, {
    js$collapse("box1")
  })
  observeEvent(input$bt2, {
    js$collapse("box2")
  })
  
  output$res <- renderPrint({
    input$iscollapsebox1
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I have very little experience with javascript so I am not really sure what could be going on here. I tried moving the call to collapseInput() around but this didn't seem to change anything.

Comment: Ummm, I may be missing something obvious, but why do you need the collapse action buttons when you have the "+" or "-" controls inside each box which have the same functionality?

Comment: Sorry if that was unclear. I am not actually interested in collapsing the boxes via the actionButtons. This was just a part of the original post and I thought it might be noteworthy that accessing the boxes via the labels still works in this case. But I am really only interested in gettting the status of the boxes (whether they are currently collapsed or not)

Comment: Instead of reinventing the wheel, you might want to check [shinydashboardPlus::box()](https://rinterface.github.io/shinydashboardPlus/articles/improved-boxes.html).

Comment: Thanks, that does make it a lot simpler :)

Answer (score 0):

Your boxes do not initially exist, so `$("#box1")` finds nothing. If you include the script in the `renderUI`, this works:

```r
  output$boxes <- renderUI({ 
    do.call(tagList, 
            list(
              box(id = "box1", collapsible = TRUE, p("Box 1")),
              box(id = "box2", collapsible = TRUE, p("Box 2")),
              collapseInput(inputId = "iscollapsebox1", boxId = "box1")
            )
    )
  })
```