# R shinyjs shinydashboard box uncollapse on radionButtons input

Tags: r, shiny, shinyjs

Based on this question [R shinyjs shinydashboard box uncollapse on action button input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49659804/r-shinyjs-shinydashboard-box-uncollapse-on-action-button-input) and question [How to manually collapse a box in shiny dashboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32104918/how-to-manually-collapse-a-box-in-shiny-dashboard), I would like to substitute the `actionButton` with the `radioButtons` (or `selectInput`). Below a reproducible example. When I click yes I want box id=B2 and id=B3 to collapse, when I click no, box id =B1 and id =B3 to collapse, and when maybe is clicked, box id=B1 and id=B2 to collapse. With the code below, there is a collapse, but it does not work as intended.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyBS)
library(dplyr)
library(shinydashboard)


# javascript code to collapse box
jscode <- "
shinyjs.collapse = function(boxid) {
$('#' + boxid).closest('.box').find('[data-widget=collapse]').click();
}
"

#Design sidebar
sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(width = 225, collapsed=F, 
                            sidebarMenu(id="tabs",
                                        menuItem("zz", tabName = "zz", selected=TRUE)))

#Design body 
body <- dashboardBody(shinyjs:::useShinyjs(), 
                      shinyjs:::extendShinyjs(text = jscode),
                      tabItems(
                        tabItem(tabName = "zz", 
                                fluidRow(box(radioButtons('go','Go', choices = c("yes", "no", "maybe"))),
                                         box(id="B1", collapsible=T,  status = "primary", color="blue", solidHeader = T, 
                                             title="Test"),
                                         box(id="B2", collapsible=T,  status = "primary", color="blue", solidHeader = T, 
                                             title="Test2"),
                                         box(id="B3", collapsible=T,  status = "primary", color="blue", solidHeader = T, 
                                             title="Test3")

                                         ))
                        ))

Header <- dashboardHeader()

#Show title and the page (includes sidebar and body)
ui <- dashboardPage(Header, sidebar, body)


server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session){

  observeEvent(input$go == "yes",

               {js$collapse("B2", "B3")}

  )
  #
  observeEvent(input$go == "no",

               {js$collapse("B1", "B3")}
  )

  observeEvent(input$go == "maybe",

               {js$collapse("B1", "B2")}
  )

})

shinyApp( ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Your collapse function works. To check if a box is collapsed you can use the functionality described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45462614/how-to-see-if-a-shiny-dashboard-box-is-collapsed-from-the-server-side

Comment: @Wilmar van Ommeren, yes there is a collapse but it does not work as intended. For example, when yes is selected, only id=B2 and id=B3 should be collapsed. As it is id=B3 is not collapse.

Comment: That is because this function does not collapse the boxes, but it toggles them. So if a box is already collapsed it will open instead of staying collapsed. Therefore, you should add a function which checks if the box is already collapsed.

Comment: @Wilmar van Ommeren. The link you provided tell if it is collapsed or not. I added the code, but how this function can be implemented to help me fix my problem. I don't know anything about JS.

Comment: check out https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/shinydashboardPlus/vignettes/improved-boxes.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The collapse function you gave actually toggles the boxes instead of only collapsing them. So you first have to check if a box is already collapsed before you want apply this function. This can be done with the function described here: [How to see if a shiny dashboard box is collapsed from the server side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45462614/how-to-see-if-a-shiny-dashboard-box-is-collapsed-from-the-server-side).

If you also want to open the remaining box you can use the same functionality.

In addition, you can put everything in a single observer to make your code a bit more consistent.

**Working example:**

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyBS)
library(dplyr)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyjs)

# javascript code to collapse box
jscode <- "
shinyjs.collapse = function(boxid) {
$('#' + boxid).closest('.box').find('[data-widget=collapse]').click();
}
"

collapseInput <- function(inputId, boxId) {
  tags$script(
    sprintf(
      "$('#%s').closest('.box').on('hidden.bs.collapse', function () {Shiny.onInputChange('%s', true);})",
      boxId, inputId
    ),
    sprintf(
      "$('#%s').closest('.box').on('shown.bs.collapse', function () {Shiny.onInputChange('%s', false);})",
      boxId, inputId
    )
  )
}

#Design sidebar
sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(width = 225, collapsed=F, 
                            sidebarMenu(id="tabs",
                                        menuItem("zz", tabName = "zz", selected=TRUE)))

#Design body 
body <- dashboardBody(shinyjs:::useShinyjs(), 
                      shinyjs:::extendShinyjs(text = jscode),
                      tabItems(
                        tabItem(tabName = "zz", 
                                fluidRow(box(radioButtons('go','Go', choices = c("yes", "no", "maybe"))),
                                         box(id="B1", collapsible=T,  status = "primary", color="blue", solidHeader = T, 
                                             title="Test"),
                                         collapseInput(inputId = "iscollapsebox1", boxId = "B1"),
                                         box(id="B2", collapsible=T,  status = "primary", color="blue", solidHeader = T, 
                                             title="Test2"),
                                         collapseInput(inputId = "iscollapsebox2", boxId = "B2"),
                                         box(id="B3", collapsible=T,  status = "primary", color="blue", solidHeader = T, 
                                             title="Test3"),
                                         collapseInput(inputId = "iscollapsebox3", boxId = "B3")
                                ))
                      ))

Header <- dashboardHeader()

#Show title and the page (includes sidebar and body)
ui <- dashboardPage(Header, sidebar, body)

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session){
  observeEvent(input$go,{
    box1_collapsed = F
    box2_collapsed = F
    box3_collapsed = F
    if (!is.null(input$iscollapsebox1)){
      box1_collapsed <- input$iscollapsebox1
    }
    if (!is.null(input$iscollapsebox2)){
      box2_collapsed <- input$iscollapsebox2
    }
    if (!is.null(input$iscollapsebox3)){
      box3_collapsed <- input$iscollapsebox3
    }
    if (input$go == 'yes'){
      if (!box2_collapsed){
        js$collapse("B2")}
      if (!box3_collapsed){
        js$collapse("B3")}
      # if you want to open B1
      if (box1_collapsed){
        js$collapse("B1")}
    } else if (input$go == 'no'){
      if (!box1_collapsed){
        js$collapse("B1")}
      if (!box3_collapsed){
        js$collapse("B3")}
      # if you want to open B2
      if (box2_collapsed){
        js$collapse("B2")}
    } else if (input$go == 'maybe'){
      if (!box1_collapsed){
        js$collapse("B1")}
      if (!box2_collapsed){
        js$collapse("B2")}
      # if you want to open B3
      if (box3_collapsed){
        js$collapse("B3")}
    }
  })
})

shinyApp( ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following functions to an external `www/custom.js` file

```
closeBox = function(boxid) {
  var box = $('#' + boxid).closest('.box');
  if (!box.hasClass('collapsed-box')) {
    box.find('[data-widget=collapse]').click();
  }
};

openBox = function(boxid) {
  var box = $('#' + boxid).closest('.box');
  if (box.hasClass('collapsed-box')) {
    box.find('[data-widget=collapse]').click();
  }
};
```

Include the .js file in dashboardBody and call the function in your app script with `shinyjs::runjs("openBox('box_id')")` or `shinyjs::runjs("closeBox('box_id')")`.

The following is a minimal working example (if you include the javascript above in a file called `custom.js` in a directory called `www` in the app directory).

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
    skin = "red",
    dashboardHeader(title = "Demo"),
    dashboardSidebar(
        actionButton("open", "Open Box"),
        actionButton("close", "Close Box")
    ),
    dashboardBody(
        shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
        tags$head(
            tags$link(rel = "stylesheet", type = "text/css", href = "custom.css"),
            tags$script(src = "custom.js")
        ),
        box(id = 'x',
            collapsible = T,
            collapsed = T,
            solidHeader = TRUE,
            title = 'Box',
            p("Hello"))
    )
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {
    observeEvent(input$open, {
        shinyjs::runjs("openBox('x')")
    }, ignoreNULL = TRUE)

    observeEvent(input$close, {
        shinyjs::runjs("closeBox('x')")
    }, ignoreNULL = TRUE)
}

# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```